# Count character length of emoji?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, emoji

I want to validate the name when a new user signs up at my page. One of those checks is if the character limit isn't above 100.

But since one single emoji like ‍❤️‍‍ (those are actually 4 emoji together? see screenshot) count much more than 1 character I have issues to validate the name. I **want** to allow emoji in the name, because these days it's quite common to have a heart, star or something similar there, but I don't want to allow names with more than 100 characters.

So I have this question:

- How to count one emoji as one character of all emojis out there (if it's even possible)?

PS: I'm talking about a php solution, but I would alternatively accept Javascript too, even if I don't prefer it.

Edit: My example emoji seems to be this string: `\ud83d\udc69\u200d\u2764\ufe0f\u200d\ud83d\udc8b\u200d\ud83d\udc69`

Please notice the mentioned screenshot of this question:

[image: The screenshot of this question, please notice the emoji output].

Comment: That PHP warning means you're passing an array to `trim` instead of a string. It's a bug in your code, no problem with PHP, and also nothing to do with emoji.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I found that error and edited my question. Thanks. @deceze

Comment: For what it's worth, this emoji consists of a sequence of 8 Unicode scalar values: U+1F469 WOMAN; U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER; U+2764 HEAVY BLACK HEART; U+FE0F VARIATION SELECTOR-16; U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER; U+1F48B KISS MARK; U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER; U+1F469 WOMAN. Some programming languages will treat WOMAN and KISS MARK as if they were two characters each, because those characters require two UTF-16 code units to represent.

Comment: Essentially… whether ‍❤️‍‍ is one or four emoji depends on whether the system it's displayed on is aware of the possible combination.

Comment: If I'm using `mb_strlen` it counts `27` characters for this single emoji. I didn't check other emojis yet, but I assume the character count is always different and way higher than just `1`. Is there even a possibility to count this as one character if its system depend like you said?

Comment: `grapheme_strlen` will count it as one character: https://3v4l.org/0cVF1

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.09 and I get this error when using this function: `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function grapheme_strlen() ...` @Federkun

Comment: you need to install intl, `apt-get install php7.0-intl`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unicode defines abstract characters as code points, but what allows for rendering it on screen is the font. A font is a collection of graphical shapes, called glyphs, and they are the visual representation of a code point or a sequence of code points. A sequence of one or more code points that are displayed as a *single graphical unit* is called **grapheme**.

If you need to get the length in grapheme units (and NOT characters, like `mb_strlen` would do), you can use [`grapheme_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.grapheme-strlen.php):

```
$emoji = "\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{2764}\u{FE0F}\u{200D}\u{1F48B}\u{200D}\u{1F469}";
echo $emoji , " : " , strlen($emoji) , "\n"; // 27, count bytes
echo $emoji , " : " , mb_strlen($emoji) , "\n"; // 8, count characters
echo $emoji , " : " , grapheme_strlen($emoji) , "\n"; // 1, count grapheme units
```

https://3v4l.org/KSSl4

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to ask you to post this as an answer. There could only be the issue that my server provider didn't install `intl` like my xampp version also didn't by default. Would there be a workaround in this case with "older" functions?

Comment: try symfony's polyfill, https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme/blob/master/Grapheme.php

Answer (score 16):

As a potential javascript solution (if you don't mind adding a library), Lodash has tackled this problem in their [toArray](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.4.0-npm-packages/lodash.toarray/index.js#L37) module.

For example,

```
_.toArray('12').length; // --> 3
```

Or, if you want to knock a few arbitrary characters off a string, you manipulate and rejoin the array, like:

```
_.toArray("trimToEightGlyphs").splice(0,8).join(''); // --> 'trimToE'
```